# How to make programs minimize when you click on them on the launcher

Tags: 12.04, launcher, lts, minimize

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I just want the programs to minimize like they do on the Windows 7 taskbar, if that gives you a idea of what I am talking about.